# How can I send a UnityEvent to specific instance of a GameObject?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a prefab representing a room. I have a unity event that is fired when a player enters, I have an event listener that changes the state of the room when the event is raised. it also changes the state of any copies of the prefab instead of the room that triggered the event.
How do I narrow the scope of an event to only the instance of the gameobject that triggers the event?

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
                RoomEnter.Raise();           
        }

public class GameEventListener : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [Tooltip("Event to register with.")]
        public GameEvent Event;

        [Tooltip("Response to invoke when Event is raised.")]
        public UnityEvent Response;

        private void OnEnable()
        {
            Event.RegisterListener(this);
        }

        private void OnDisable()
        {
            Event.UnregisterListener(this);
        }

        public void OnEventRaised()
        {
            Response.Invoke();
        }
    }

public class GameEvent : ScriptableObject
    {
        /// The list of listeners that this event will notify if it is raised.
        private readonly List<GameEventListener> eventListeners = 
            new List<GameEventListener>();

        public void Raise()
        {
            for(int i = eventListeners.Count -1; i >= 0; i--)
                eventListeners[i].OnEventRaised();
        }

        public void RegisterListener(GameEventListener listener)
        {
            if (!eventListeners.Contains(listener))
                eventListeners.Add(listener);
        }

        public void UnregisterListener(GameEventListener listener)
        {
            if (eventListeners.Contains(listener))
                eventListeners.Remove(listener);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why use event? When the player enter, just call the method of THIS room.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        GetComponent<GameEventListener>().OnEventRaised();
    }
}
```

Comment: as I expand my code I'd like multiple things to trigger from different systems and I'd prefer to keep them decoupled if possible. wouldn't I need to pull in all the different systems with listeners this way?

Comment: Usually event system is a system to send message from 1 trigger to other receivers. And in your example the trigger and receiver are the same thing, it's redundant to use an event system. If you still prefer it, it's ok, but need keep 1 `RoomEnter` instance for 1 room.

Comment: shingo is right. You can't have an even that notifies everyone and yet not notify everyone. If you insist on events you can have 2, one global and second one unique per room. Or you could send the room instance as event parameter and some handler to process it only if its the same room it is part of.

Comment: you can actually do what Nikaas say. create a Component for your GameObject with a public string (for example) with getter. You can than initialize that string in the editor, and check if other.CompareTag("Player") && other.GetComponent<YourComponent>().YourPublicString == "SpecificObject".